# OpenID error messages on python-openid

Tags: openid, yahoo, janrain

I'm using the python-openid library from Janrain at

http://openidenabled.com/python-openid/

I adapted their Django example to another framework called Web2Py and it appears to be working, but with some annoying side-effects.

1. The first problem is that sreg (Simple Registration Extension) and ax (Attribute Exchange) don't seem to work. I know that Google uses ax, but my openID consumer always returns None for both of them.
2. Whenever I login with Google it spews an annoying error message on stdout. It appears to be working, but could be indicative of larger problems?

   Error attempting to use stored discovery information: < openid.consumer.consumer.
   TypeURIMismatch: Required type http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/signon not found
    in ['http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server', 'http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0',
   'http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/mode/popup', 'http://specs.openid.net
   /extensions/ui/1.0/icon', 'http://specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0'] for end
   point https://www.go
   ogle.com/accounts/o8/ud' claimed_id=None local_id=None canonicalID=None used_yad
   is=True
3. When I turn on stateless mode, Google actually doesn't display an error anymore, but instead its Yahoo's turn:

   Received "invalidate_handle" from server https://open.login.yahooapis.com/openid
   /op/auth

Does anyone have any insight to these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you use Python 2.5. I am also trying to use openid with web2py and was always returned None by SReg when using 2.6.

Regards,
HC

http://w2popenid.appspot.com

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and it really made me becoming crazy but I found the solution here [python-openid doesn't provide ax or sreg attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979260/python-openid-doesnt-provide-ax-or-sreg-attributes) and it worked for me.