# python-openid doesn't provide ax or sreg attributes

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, openid

I've been able to finally get python-openid to authenticate a user, but I'm not able to create a sreg.SRegResponse or ax.FetchResponse as they come back as None.  This is coming from a Google Apps account and I'm trying to follow the example from https://github.com/openid/python-openid/tree/master/examples/djopenid.  I've heard Google's OpenID system can be a little funky and require some tweaks like [Retrieve OpenID AX attributes from Google / Yahoo in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956522/retrieve-openid-ax-attributes-from-google-yahoo-in-rails)

```
    response = c.complete(request_args, return_to)

    sreg_response = sreg.SRegResponse.fromSuccessResponse(response)
    ax_response = ax.FetchResponse.fromSuccessResponse(response)
```

The response is definitely coming back as a SUCCESS, but I see the following error message, which may be related:

```
Generated checkid_setup request to https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud with assocication AOQobUdVBCrd-GZRcasn9tD-yOUF0Y8pJLAQrYXODqLxUUjN62G1BXR1
Error attempting to use stored discovery information: <openid.consumer.consumer.TypeURIMismatch: Required type http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/signon not found in ['http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server', 'http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0', 'http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/mode/popup', 'http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/icon', 'http://specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0'] for endpoint <openid.consumer.discover.OpenIDServiceEndpoint server_url='https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud' claimed_id=None local_id=None canonicalID=None used_yadis=True >>
Attempting discovery to verify endpoint
Performing discovery on https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawkKU4uzJV9Q_FGMECNGsbiXG2caISYMyCw
Received id_res response from https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud using association AOQobUdVBCrd-GZRcasn9tD-yOUF0Y8pJLAQrYXODqLxUUjN62G1BXR1
```

Here's my setup.

```
           sreg_request = sreg.SRegRequest(optional=['email', 'nickname'],
                                        required=['dob'])
            auth_request.addExtension(sreg_request)

            # Add Attribute Exchange request information.
            ax_request = ax.FetchRequest()
            # XXX - uses myOpenID-compatible schema values, which are
            # not those listed at axschema.org.
            ax_request.add(ax.AttrInfo('http://schema.openid.net/namePerson',
                                       required=True))
            ax_request.add(ax.AttrInfo('http://schema.openid.net/contact/web/default',
                                       required=False, count=ax.UNLIMITED_VALUES))
            auth_request.addExtension(ax_request)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having problems with Google returning not the `schema.openid.net` values for AttributeExchange. It was returning None just like you mentioned, and the worst part is that it used to work when I first wrote my OpenID handlers.

Once I switched over to the axschema values in my implementation, it worked like a charm. ex:

```
    URLS = {
      'ax_email': 'http://axschema.org/contact/email',
      'ax_first': 'http://axschema.org/namePerson/first',
    }

    ...

    ax_request = ax.FetchRequest()
    ax_request.add(ax.AttrInfo(URLS['ax_email'], required = True))
    ax_request.add(ax.AttrInfo(URLS['ax_first'], required = True))

    auth_request.addExtension(ax_request)
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but I forgot about this thread and moved on to other things in my project.  By the time I got back to the OpenID portion, I had to get back to the original problem posted before trying your fixed, which worked great.

Comment: Bingo! Works now with my Pyramid application. Thanks :-)